# How can I update my current selection of indexes in a QTreeView?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

I'm trying to drag and drop several items from a view in a widget to another view in another widget. But I don't want to drop already existing items : for example, if I have itemA and itemB in the drop area, and I'm dragging itemA and itemC, I want itemC to be dropped but not itemA. How can I do that?

I tried to play with the selectionModel() but it doesn't seem to work (or I am not using it correctly) :

```
void myWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent * event)
{
    bool dropOK;

    // retrieve the source model
    QObject* source = event->source();
    QTreeView* viewSource = dynamic_cast<QTreeView*>(source);
    QStandardItemModel* modelSource = (QStandardItemModel*)viewSource->model();

    // retrieve the item dragged
    QModelIndex sourceIndex = viewSource->selectionModel()->currentIndex();

    QModelIndex dropIndex = indexAt(event->pos());
    DropIndicatorPosition dropIndicator = dropIndicatorPosition();

    /* loop for each item selected (itemA and itemC in my example) */
    for (int i = 0; i < viewSource->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes().count() ; i++)
    {
        dropOK = true;

        QStandardItem* itemSource = modelSource->itemFromIndex(viewSource->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes().at(i));

        QString strUIDSource = itemSource->data(Qt::UserRole).toString();

        if (dropIndex.parent().isValid() && dropIndex.row() != -1)
        {
            switch (dropIndicator)
            {
                case QAbstractItemView::AboveItem:
                dropOK = true;
                break;
                // and so on...
            }

            if (dropOK == true)
            {
                int siblingCount = dropIndex.model()->rowCount(dropIndex.parent());
                for (int iSibling = 0; iSibling < siblingCount; iSibling++)
                {
                    QModelIndex siblingIndex = dropIndex.sibling(iSibling, 0);
                    QStandardItem* currentItem = m_pModel->itemFromIndex(siblingIndex);
                    // we compare items from source with items in the drop area according to their data
                    QString strUIDCurrent = currentItem->data(Qt::UserRole).toString();

                    if (dropIndex.parent() == viewSource->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes().at(i).parent())
                        dropOK = true;
                    else
                    {
                        //if data source == data current, we don't drop 
                        if (strUIDSource == strUIDCurrent)
                        {
                            dropOK = false;
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (strUIDSource != strUIDCurrent)
                            dropOK = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
       else
           dropOK = false;
    }
   if (dropOK)
       QTreeView::dropEvent(event);
}
```

When dropOK is true, itemA and itemC are dropped, even if I entered the "if (!dropOK)" before...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is that how you have overridden the dropEvent of your widget.?

Comment: Do you intend to add these items at a specific location..?
Meaning at the location of the mouse, or in the top of other treeview or bottom of it.
For me, since you already know what is to be dropped, why don't you manually add those items in the treeview where you intend to drop them, and then accept the drop event rather than passing it over to QTreeView..?

This should work out...

Comment: It's not working, I still have the same problem... Plus, my items dropped don't appear in the tree view, I mean, they are here, but not their name, its just an empty space..
And yes, I know where they're going to be dropped, so I used sth like `QStandardItem parent = ...`, then `parent->appendRow(itemC)`

Comment: Can you post a bit more of code if possible, It is fairly difficult to figure out just from this snippet on what you are actually doing

Comment: @PRIME here it is, I edited the original post